# Почему я не могу обратитьтся к свойству объекта именно так?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Snake:

    def __int__(self):
        self.life = True
        self.size = 0
        self.X = 3
        self.Y = 3


snake = Snake()

print(snake.life)

AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'life'
```

Answer (score 3):

потому что конструктора в классе нет, в котором вы и инициализировали переменные

```
def __int__(self):
```

это не конструктор :)

```
def __init__(self):
```

а вот это конструктор

P.S.

кстати, если сделать такой код, то он будет работать:

```
class Snake:
    def __int__(self):
        self.life = True
        self.size = 0
        self.X = 3
        self.Y = 3
        return 0


snake = Snake()

int(snake)

print(snake.life)
```

Comment: только сейчас догадался!

Comment: если бы вы добавили `return` числа в этот метод, а потом где-то вызвали бы `int(snake)`, то все заработало бы :) поэтому аккуратнее с именами функций